# Html body onLoad is called on redirect from HttpServletResponse

Tags: jsf

I have the following html page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

          <h:head>

            </h:head>

       <h:body  onload="#{login.activateAccount()}" >
        <h:form  id="formRegister">
         <p:panel  style="border:none;  width: 0px; height: 0px; margin-left:-15px ; " id="panelMesaje"> </p:panel>
        </h:form>
       </h:body>   
    </html>
```

When the page is loaded  the following method is called and everything works fine.

```
  public String activateAccount() {

        try {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

            String random = request.getParameter("random");

            log.error("method called" + random);
            addActivatedInfoMessage("Your account has been activated.");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("unexpected error", ex);
            addErrorMessage("An unexpected errors has occured.Please try again a bit later.");
        }

        return "OK";
    }
```

In this method a primefaces dialog will be rendered if everything is ok.

```
  private void addActivatedInfoMessage(String text) {
        UIComponent panel = ComponentUtils.findComponent("panelMesaje");
        Dialog dialogx=(Dialog) ComponentUtils.findComponent("infoMessageDialog");
        if (ComponentUtils.findComponent("infoMessageDialog") != null) {
        panel.getChildren().remove(dialogx);

        }
            int panelHeight=text.trim().length()/2;
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
            dialog.setStyleClass("clasaDialogInfo");
            dialog.setResizable(false); 
            dialog.setDynamic(true);
            dialog.setClosable(false);
            dialog.setWidgetVar("infoMessageDialog");  
            dialog.setId("infoMessageDialog");
            dialog.setModal(true);           



          log.info(" panel height este "+panelHeight);

            ScrollPanel panelScroll = new ScrollPanel();
            panelScroll.setStyle("text-align: center;border:none;width:100%;heigth:"+panelHeight+"px;font-size:20px !important");
//            HtmlPanelGroup hpg=new HtmlPanelGroup();

            HtmlOutputLabel  hit = new HtmlOutputLabel();
            hit.setValue(text);

            hit.setStyle("text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;margin-top: 0px");
            hit.setId("inputhtmlmesajeInfo");
//            hpg.getChildren().add(hit);
            panelScroll.getChildren().add(hit);
            Panel panelButon = new Panel();
            panelButon.setStyle("border:none;text-align: center;height: 37px;margin-bottom: 2px");
            HtmlCommandButton button = new HtmlCommandButton();
            button.setValue("Log in");
            button.setStyle("text-align: center;width:40%;height: 33px;margin-bottom: 2px;font-size:20px !important");



            button.setActionExpression(createMethodExpression("#{login.redirectToLogin}"));;

            panelButon.getChildren().add(button);
            dialog.getChildren().add(panelScroll);
            dialog.getChildren().add(panelButon);
            panel.getChildren().add(dialog);


        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('infoMessageDialog').show()");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(panel.getClientId());

    }
```

Next when i click the command button added to that dialog it will try to redirect to login using

```
public void  redirectToLogin (){
        try {
            ((HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse()).sendRedirect("login.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           log.error("eroare la redirect ",ex);
        }
         }
```

All works fine ,but body onload method is called again before redirecting.I tried to put a jsf command button directly in the page to see if that happens but didn't. The question is why when button is added dynamic the onLoad is called again before redirect and when its added directly to html (like this `<h:commandButton action="login.xhtml" value="login.xhtml"/>` 
)  wont be called?
I am using   following jsf version

```
 compile ('com.sun.faces:jsf-api:2.2.8')   { transitive = false }
compile ('com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:2.2.8')   { transitive = false }
```

Comment: The position of the `h:form` is weird, very weird (and might even be part of the cause of your problem). Correct that first please

Comment: i change it , same behavior .

Comment: i solve the problem by changing  the redirectToLogin method with  public String  redirectToLogin (){
         return "login.xhtml";
         }